# Можно ли асинхронно обновить php код?

Tags: ajax, php, html, javascript

Есть ф-ция на js которая вызывается по клику на элементе.

```
function sendtime()
{
    var param3='<?php echo date("s")?>';
    alert(param3);
}
```

Меня интересует, реально ли с помощью Ajax, без перезагрузки всей страницы, обновить эту часть `var param3='<?php echo date("s")?>';`

И если реально, то как?

Answer (score 3):

Реально. Сделайте отдельный php файл, который будет возвращать значение даты. И вызывайте его из JS асинхронно. Как-то так:

```
// date.php
echo date("s");
```

и

```
// ваш js, понадобится jQuery
function sendtime(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://site.ru/date.php',
        success: function( data) {
            alert( data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @sergiks это не совсем то. Я знал, что можно таким способом, но проблема немного глубже.

Comment: зачем создавать проблему там, где её нет?

Посмотрите на это с другой стороны: 

 1. PHP код может отрабатывать только на стороне сервера;
 2. он показывает текущее серверное время в секундаах;
 3. страница загружена в браузер пользователя. Через какое-то время после этого, **на сервере** должен снова отработать php код, а результат оказаться в уже загруженной странице в браузере пользователя.

Только ajax, только хардкор!

Comment: @sergiks
Я потробнее описал тут http://hashcode.ru/questions/337803/php-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы и нет? Только есть одно НО, именно в этом случае я лично вариантов не вижу, что б без перезагрузки обновить, а так обрщайтесь аяксом к скрипту, который даст вам нужный результат и вешайте ответ